# Update SharePoint Library column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I've been using validateUpdateListItem() to update a person field without issue.

The problem is that for some reason it works on certain document items and not others in the library. It hangs with 'Bad Gateway' error.

The library has Major Version and Approval enabled and the item I'm trying to update are in Draft and not checked out.

As a test, I'm trying now to upate a Text column 'Editor2' with email address rather than a persons column, and the gateway error persists. Any ideas of what the issue could be?
Is there another method without updating version number?

[image]

```
"innerError": {
      "status": 502,
      "message": "Additions to this Web site have been blocked.\n\nPlease contact the administrator to resolve this problem.\r\nclientRequestId: fb5b80e6-bcce-4a71-86eb-007ff1ab17be\r\nserviceRequestId: cce1c2a0-906e-6000-b11a-0a010018fbb6",
      "source": "https://zzz.sharepoint.com/sites/test78/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Training%20Material%20Test')/items(233)/validateUpdateListItem",
```

Comment: Did you or someone make this SharePoint site collection read-only? If yes, you will have to remove read-only settings. let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "Additions to this Web site have been blocked", it could be that the SharePoint site you are visiting has some sort of restriction that prevents additions to that site.

Comment: What about trying to update the data after the file is checked out?